# Angular 6 with bootstrap UI renders blank screen in IE sporadically

Tags: angular

We have an Angular 6 application which is deployed in production PCF server. Post production there is a blank page (when inspected, htmls are rendered but, shows white screen) issue that is happening sporadically in end user machine

Often the UI is flickering.

One thing noticed in users machine is, resizing the window gets the screen appearing.

We are using Angular version 6
Bootstrap 4

Really appreciate any help on this issue

Comment: ❤️ IE sporadically. Check your pollyfills, try if there are console errors, I mean there are no straight forward answers for "IE"

Comment: There is no console error when this happen. Also, all the polyfills are enabled as per polyfills.ts